# Implementing a UIImageView in a UITableViewCell only when certain conditions are met with Core Data and NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm relatively new to iOS development and I have a question to which I believe the answer is easy, but I can't seem to find a way to achieve it.

I have a `UITableViewController` which is populated by the user tapping on a button on the `NavigationBar` where the user fills in the Name, Event, Sub-Event, Amount, Date, Status and Optionally Notes. The data is saved to `CoreData` and the `UITableView` is populated with `NSFetchedResultsController`.

The notes are completely optional and it takes the form of a `UITextView`, where the other text based entries are `UITextFields`.

The notes attribute is part of a Transaction Entity and is a `NSString`.

Because there's no way (that I can see) to have a placeholder for the `UITextView`, I've set up the default text to say "Additional Notes: " with the space at the end.

In my `UITableViewController`, I want the `UIImageView` (that represents the note) to only appear if:

1) The user types something completely different to "Additional Notes: " &

2) If the length of the notes textView is bigger than 0

So in my UITableViewController cellForRow, I have:

```
if (![transaction.notes isEqualToString:@"Additional Notes: "] && [transaction.notes length] > 0)
{
    UIImageView *pin = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 30, 24, 25)];
    pin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin"];
    [customCell addSubview:pin];
}
```

That's working to some extent. If I add text to "Additional Notes: ", it adds the PIN to the cell.

**Problems**

If I remove a few letters in the notes, so "Additional Not ", it treats the if statement as true and therefore attaches a pin to the statement.

If I have a note called "Additional Notes: This is a test note", it shows the PIN in the cell. However, if I go to edit that entry and remove "This is a test note", so it's back to the default, it doesn't remove the PIN from the cell of this UITableViewController.

So my questions are:

1) Can I have a placeholder for the notes? That would solve all of my issues

2) If not, how can I achieve this process efficiently, so it's not misleading for the users thinking they have a note if they just removed one or two letters

3) Have updated notes reflect appropriately in the `UITableViewController`

Any guidance would be really appreciated

Comment: One thing you can do is to remove the full "Additional Notes: " placeholder text when user starts typing or editing the textView. Check if the text is equal to Placeholder and set the text to nilwhen edit begins.

Comment: Thanks @borncrazy - I was thinking about this approach actually, but because the view is Transparent, if I remove "Additional Notes", if the user taps the UITextView and then decides not to add a note, that's just a blank space with no notes.. but I think you're on the right idea..

Comment: That could possibly be solved if you recheck the text after editing and provide the placeholder accordingly. Since you might be checking the scenario when user will only be entering blank spaces.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean. Would that be in the should/DidEndEditing delegate method of the UITextView?

Comment: Provided you the way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :-

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {

    if([[textView text] isEqualToString:@"Additional Notes: "]){
        [textView setText:@""];
    }
    return YES;

}

- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {

    if([[[textView text] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] isEqualToString:@""]){
        [textView setText:@"Additional Notes: "];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

This will handle the whitespaces and new lines only scenario.

Comment: Many thanks @borncrazy - that is very helpful. One thing I'm noticing now though is inconsistency with the UITableView. If I create a new entry with no notes, the note pin doesn't get appended to the cell (so far so good). If I go in and edit the entry with a note, the pin appears in the UITableView (so far so good). However if I go back to the entry, remove the note (it then appends "Additional Notes: " back to it but the cell still has a note pin, indicating that the length is greater than 0 which is true, but does not equal "Additional Notes :", not true - as per the if statement

Comment: of the original question in the UITableView

Comment: you have to update your cell's transaction.notes each time after the text has been entered.

Comment: Deleted previous comment for brevity (it's not the CoreData issue). In the scenario in my comment above, if I add an entry with no note, edit it and put the note and then edit it again and take out the note, the PIN remains in the cell, but disappears after I reload the view (like close the app off), which means it just needs to be reloaded. I'm guessing a [self.tableview reloadData]; in the viewWillAppear or something

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do it. I'm so sorry for so many questions; how would I update the cell's transaction.notes? The "save" method of the edit sets the notesTextView to the edited entries from the user..

Comment: I'm going to create another question for my issue because it's different from the original question here, but i do really thank you for your response because I got that part working like a charm - thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

the first approach: You need set text default, and change its color: gray ..smt like placeholder of textfield. Then your cell implement Textview delegate:

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView;
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView;
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text;
```

textViewShouldBegin: to remove the default textview

textViewDidChange: check your lenght textview >0 & text != defaulttext

textShouldChange..: check like textViewDidChange and In case: you are typing, and still editing in your cell.